# mysql ft_min_word_len change on ubuntu does not work

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, full-text-search

I am trying to implement the full test search. And for this the first thing I did change the value of `ft_min_word_len = 2` on /etc/mysql/my.cnf as

```
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#

#
# * IMPORTANT
#   If you make changes to these settings and your system uses apparmor, you may
#   also need to also adjust /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld.
#
ft_min_word_len = 2
```

Now Saved that and restarted the server.
I am aware that if I already have an index with FULLTEXT in a table I will need to drop the indexes and rebuilt, or repair the table.
But I have created the table as

```
create table 
`comments` 
(   `id` int(11), 
    `comment` varchar(200), 
    `iduser` int(11) , 
    `date_added` datetime
) 
ENGINE=MyISAM;

ALTER TABLE comments
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX comment_index
(comment);
```

Then in the above table I have some comments added manually.

When I try to search something as

```
SELECT * FROM comments where MATCH (comment) AGAINST ('the') ; // "the" is very common word of length to see my test result
```

It returns 0 rows.

However if I set AGAINST with a word length of 4 it works.

I tried to check the ft_ variables as

```
mysql>  show variables like 'ft_%';
+--------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name            | Value          |
+--------------------------+----------------+
| ft_boolean_syntax        | + -><()~*:""&| |
| ft_max_word_len          | 84             |
| ft_min_word_len          | 2              |
| ft_query_expansion_limit | 20             |
| ft_stopword_file         | (built-in)     |
+--------------------------+----------------+
```

Interesting thing is in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` I can only see `ft_min_word_len` but the `ft_max_word_len` is not there and more importantly the search less than length 4 does not work atall.

This is making me crazy and not sure if there is some other config which is over writing everything and seems like not able locate them either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Mysql Version in my development machine is

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.63, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to found the issue and the fix.

The full text search setting was good since I wanted to search with alt east  2 words and I had `ft_min_word_len = 2`

Now while doing more testing I found it randomly does search for few 2 character words and ignores other.

Here is an example

```
CREATE TABLE articles (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(200),
    body TEXT,
    FULLTEXT (title,body)
);

INSERT INTO articles (title,body) VALUES
('MySQL Tutorial','DBMS stands for DataBase ...'),
('How To Use MySQL Well','After you went through a ...'),
('Optimizing MySQL','In this tutorial we will show ...'),
('1001 MySQL Tricks','1. Never run mysqld as root. 2. ...'),
('MySQL vs. YourSQL','In the following database comparison ...'),
('MySQL Security','When configured properly, MySQL ...');

mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('use');
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('Use');
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('you');
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('the');
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('vs.');
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

But the following works

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles
    -> WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('run');
+----+-------------------+-------------------------------------+
| id | title             | body                                |
+----+-------------------+-------------------------------------+
|  4 | 1001 MySQL Tricks | 1. Never run mysqld as root. 2. ... |
+----+-------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

So its something else and apparently found its the `ft_stopword_file` which has a list of words and does not do anything if any search happens with one of them.

The list is here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

So in this case to allow any word search of length at least 2 character long

- Set the ft_min_word_len to 2
- Then in the mysql config file , for debian /etc/mysql/my.cnf add **ft_stopword_file='path/to/stopword_file.txt'**
- We can leave this file blank if needed.

Oh one more thing once we do the above settings we need to restart mysql and if we change `ft_min_word_len` then we need to re-built the index or repair the table.