# Mysql Fulltext search returns empty result while there are 100+ rows

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

The query I use to get rows:

```
SELECT * FROM `sentence` WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST('hello')
```

Mysql returns empty result when I run this query.

However if I use LIKE keyword to get rows

```
SELECT * FROM `sentence` WHERE text LIKE '%hello%'
```

Then, Mysql returns 144 rows.

And lets come to a more weird thing

Mysql fulltext works properly for some words o.O

For example when I search 'killer' word, LIKE returns 44 and Fulltext returns 20 which is okay for me.

This situation doesn't make sense to me. Please explain this and suggest a solution.

Comment: Add an example of some columns that DOESN'T match and that you think should in an example table.

Comment: Add your db with some data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first situation i.e. `hello` returing nothing, its the fulltext search stopwords which is not doing anything when you search for the word `hello`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

You can setup your own file as

- In the mysql config file , for debian /etc/mysql/my.cnf add ft_stopword_file='path/to/stopword_file.txt'
- We can leave this file blank if needed.

The 2nd case `killer` not returning the expected number of rows, and this could be of various reasons

- whitespace in the word
- case sensitivity issue.
- and fulltext search will only match a `complete word` as you are trying it will not do a pattern matching with `AGAINST('killer')` but using `like '%killer%'` will match anything has the string `killer`.

To replicate the issue and to see the cause of the problem if you create a fiddle that would be helpful. But for the first case its the stopword list which is why you are getting 0 rows.

Here is something similar which I faced before

[mysql ft_min_word_len change on ubuntu does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21777749/mysql-ft-min-word-len-change-on-ubuntu-does-not-work)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Appearently, this problem occured because 'hello' is a stopword. I changed the engine from MyIsam to InnoDB which doesn't have a stopword 'hello' and problem solved. And i changed the stopword file to avoid such problems

Comment: Right, InnoDB does not have that issue.